# Automatica drag and drop -MouseEvent- Selenium - AutoIt

Tags: c#, selenium, drag-and-drop

I have a question about the Drag and Drop. So i try to describe my scenario.

I have an **APP_1** (it's a interface that return the path of some files. Written in C#)

I have an **APP_2** (that create on desktop a drag and drop zone, where you can release over the file.. after some seconds it generates a combine file. This is written in C++).

Now, i have that when **APP_1** finish. It start the **APP_2**

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\UPGRADE.exe");
```

**Constraints**

I can't modify **APP_2**, i have only the exe file.

**QUESTION**

Is there a *AUTOMATIC way* in C# to pass/send/submit some files in a drag and drop zone create by another app?

I accept also solution whith other dll o with batch to send file. Only constraint is that i can't modify **APP_2** and i doesn't want manually the drag and drop

I know a little bit about **MouseEventArgs**

Regards,
J

Comment: I have try some ideas but without good result. I would know if someone knows a dll o similar to make this, because i don't have any idea about create this.

Comment: But how can this relate to `selenium` ? Am I missing something?